# Showing starting text of Mulitline TextBox when focus is changed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

I am creating a form which has a **Multiline** `TextBox` to enter an URL. Expected URLs will be very long.
User will paste the URL and move to next box.

Right now, `TextBox` shows ending part of the URL when user moves to next `TextBox`. I want such that it will show starting of URL (Domain name) instead of trailing part.

Current:

[image: Current behaviour]

Expected:

[image: Expected behaviour]

And this should happen when user leaves the `TextBox`.

I tried various methods of `Selection` in `textBox_Leave()` event but I guess, these methods won't work if focus is lost.

I am using .Net framework 3.5.

**Update**: Textbox I am using is Multiline. Answers suggested by @S.Akbari and @Szer are perfect if the `Mutliline` property is set to False. I realized it late that `Multiline` will play such a significant role. Hence updating the question!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`SelectionStart`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectionstart(v=vs.110).aspx) in the `Leave` event should works:

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     textBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
}
```

Before:

[image]

After leaving `TextBox`:

[image]

Comment: Already tried... Doesnot work! It hits the breakpoint as well if I put it there but no action

Comment: @Swanand...Are you sure that you tried `SelectionStart` ?? Try it again with my code. It now works for me without any problem!

Comment: @user2946329 Yes... Exactly same line... Let me debug more... (P.S. I didn't down vote)

Comment: @user2946329 I created a different project, With only two textboxes, It works there :-( Something is wrong with my actual project.

Comment: @user2946329 It works but if I set "Multiline" Property as "True", This stops working.

Answer (score 2):

Tried it and it works. [Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frzLB.jpg)

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    textBox1.LostFocus += TextBox1_LostFocus;
}

private void TextBox1_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
    textBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
}
```

Comment: `LostFocus` is not a good place. For instance `Alt-Tab` tow switch to another app, then `Alt+Tab` to switch back .

Comment: @IvanStoev right. Event itself not a question, but good point.

Comment: @CodyGray Not really (otherwise why having 2 separate events). `Leave` is fired when `ContainerControl.ActiveControl` changes, which is different from physically losing the input focus. "Logical" vs "Physical" focus :)

Comment: @Ivan Thanks. Makes sense. Actually, I was thinking that `Leave` was just for VB 6 compatibility. I didn't realize under what conditions it was raised. Been too long out of the WinForms world to remember the nuances of that model. :-)

Comment: @Szer It works but if I set "Multiline" Property as "True", This stops working

Answer (score 1):

I can see how it doesn't work with the Multiline property set to true.

A simple API call can make this work:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

private const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x115;
private const int SB_TOP = 6;

void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  SendMessage(textBox1.Handle, WM_VSCROLL, (IntPtr)SB_TOP, IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

Comment: @Swanand Updated post with a cleaner solution.

Comment: Thanks... But you should have kept both answers!